# Lambda vs function for sorting

Tags: c++, lambda

I have a class

```
class Point
{
private:
  int x; int y; 
public:
  Point(int a, int b):x(a),y(b){}
  Point():Point(0,0){}
}
```

If I want to sort a vector of `Point`s, shall I use a lambda:

```
std::sort(xSortedPoints.begin(), xSortedPoints.end(),
          [](const cv::Point& p1In, const cv::Point& p2In) -> bool {
              return (p1In.x < p2In.x);
          });
```

or using a static function in the class:

```
std::sort(xSortedPoints.begin(), xSortedPoints.end(), xSorting);
```

where `xSorting` is defined and declared in the `Point` class as

```
static bool xSorting(const Point& p1In, const Point& p2In)
{
  return (p1In.x < p2In.x);
}
```

Why shall I use lambda, or why not?

---

**EDIT:**

Because I need to sort in the two ways (by `x` and by `y`) I did not define the `<` operator.

Based on the comments and answers I need to say that I use this in an application that runs continuously, so the sorting is done a lot of times. So what is better to use in my case: static or lambdas? Lambdas are created every time the `std::sort` is used? If yes, than I think static is the best choice... No?

Comment: There's a third alternative, that you define an `<` operator for your class. Then you don't need to pass a third argument to `std::sort` at all.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Although it may make sense for a particular sorting function, an overloaded comparison operator doesn't always make sense in a global context.  Lambdas are nice in keeping a single function localized to its one respective duty.

This is a pretty opinionated question though; all 3 are valid style preferences.

Comment: I have edited with more info... but it seems that I shall use the static one in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda would make the code more concise especially if it's a one-liner like in your case.  On the other hand, I would think the static function approach would be prefered if it needs to or can be used in more than 1 place.

Answer (score 3):

Lambdas are there for convenience and *slick* code.

If you prefer to use a static function you should do this. If you use it once consider a lambda.
To my knowledge there is no performance gain when using lambdas.

So either do a static function, put an in place lambda or define less than operator for the class.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of opinion based but in short:

If it is short and not used often, use a lambda. Your example is short enough. If the function is long or complicated or used often, give it a name.

In this special case, you could think about overloading `operator <` for `Point` if it makes sense. Then, no third argument to `sort` would be required, but you have make sure that `<` does what the naive reader would expect.

Btw, you can omit the `->bool`, the compiler will deduce it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is any performance issues here, and the answers you get are going to be of the type "IM(H)O ....", so here are my two cents:

In this case, lambda is good in the sense that it shows the person who is reading the code what you mean by comparing two points. Mathematically, 2D (or any higher dimensions for that matter) points don't form an ordered set, so a `<` operator will be confusing. Having a static function, friend, ... on the other hand puts the definition of the comparison too far from the usage and, again, might add to confusion as the reader has to scroll to the definition to see what you mean by comparing two points.