# Sort QList<SerialPortinfo>

Tags: qt, sorting, qlist

I have a `QList` of `SerialPortInfo` objects. I want to sort it based on the objects' property `portName`.

I tried `qSort`, but that has been deprecated and it won't compile. I am trying `std::sort` but not working so far since not sure what to put at the ??? parameter. I see some examples of std::sort but  seems not relevant to my case.

```
 std::sort(serialPortInfoList.first(),serialPortInfoList.end(),???)
```

Comment: Example of two ways to do it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24913642/lambda-vs-function-for-sorting

Comment: `qSort` won't compile? My project is using very recent Qt 5.9 and just checked: nobody bothered replacing `qSort` with `std::sort`, though why not.

Comment: @AlexanderVX, it works thank you. I think there was some other error that made it cant compile.